# How to set environment variables for javac to be able to find imported packages?

Tags: java, classpath, environment-variables, environment

I am not a java developer. I just want to run a java application (which can be downloaded from:
 http://code.google.com/p/k-shortest-paths/downloads/list
, under this name:        KShortestPaths_Java_v2.1.zip)

While trying to compile test\edu\asu\emit\qyan\test\YenTopKShortestPathsAlgTest.java 
I get "package ... does not exist" and "symbol ... does not exist" which I know are related to path setting. Can you please tell me how I should set environment variables and from which directory compile and run that java file? 
(My operating system is Windows XP and I have saved the application in C:\KSh)

Edit:
I resolved the problem with compiling. Now, I have a CLASS file: YenTopKShortestPathsAlgTest. However, when I try to run it with java, I get this error: "could not find the main class... program will exist"
which I guess is again related to the paths other jar files are located. Could you please kindly give me a hint?

Answer (score 2):

The zip file contains a `.classpath` and a `.project` file. These files are used by the eclipse java IDE.

Perhaps the most easy way would be to [download eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/galileo/SR1/eclipse-java-galileo-SR1-win32.zip) and import the project there.

If you want to do it by hand, try

```
javac -sourcepath src;test test\edu\asu\emit\qyan\test\YenTopKShortestPathsAlgTest.java
```

from your directory `C:\KSh`.

**EDIT:**

Download [junit.jar](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1.jar?use_mirror=switch) and add it to the classpath with

```
javac -classpath junit.jar -sourcepath....
```

Comment: Thanks. First there was 18 errors, but now I have still 1 
"package org.junit does not exist" error 
and 4 "cannot find symbol" errors as follows:
Symbol: class Test
location: class edu.asu.emit.qyan.test.YenTopKShortestPathsAlgTest
@Test

Comment: @Matin - JUnit is a test framework library available from http://www.junit.org/ You will need to add the appropriate JAR dependency to your classpath.

Comment: Sorry for being such a beginner, but where should I save it? I still have those errors?

Answer (score 2):

You need to point the classpath to the name of the .jar files, and/or the name of the directory containing your class files e.g.

```
CLASSPATH=c:\dir\myjar.jar;c:\classes
```

so you list the .jars required and the directories involved, separated by semicolons. You can either set the CLASSPATH environment variable, or use the above directly with `javac` thus:

```
javac -cp c:\dir\myjar.jar;c:\classes {source files}
```